# There are only 2 candidates in 2018 - how do I make a 3rd choice?

Tags: support, election

I was informed by the system that I should cast my vote on Software Recommendations. I attempted to do so, but there are only two candidates.

I chose my first 2 choices, obviously. However, I can't vote for the same person twice - and there is no one else to vote for!

What should I do in this situation? Will my two choices count or do I **need** to make a third choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to make a third choice.

Your first two choices will be counted, in that order, don't worry.

The long-term solution is to post more answers and questions, gain reputation, do reviews, gain moderation experience, and nominate yourself next time :-)

Comment: Actually, [you can also pass the second choice!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77466/will-my-vote-be-valid-if-i-only-use-one-of-the-three-in-the-moderator-election), especially since there are only 2 candidates for 1 position... (the second choice will be moot)

Answer (score 2):

Well in *this* case its moot.

With two choices and *one* place, whoever gets more first choices is likely to win.

STV gets interesting when there's two or more places with sufficiently high participation in the election, but here... it doesn't quite matter.